# Automatically load the URL from link field into a script

Tags: entities, display-suite

I have a content type "Team" to add team members. In this content type I have a link field (called "LinkedIn") which holds the URL to the team member's LinkedIn page.
What I want is to use the URL from the link field and use it with a script (provided by LinkedIn). The script looks like this:

```
<script src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/MemberProfile" data-id="linkedin-profile-link.com" data-format="hover"></script>
```

I have created a simple text field for the content type "Team" and in a team member node of that content type I copied above code into it and inserted the URL from the "LinkedIn" link field. This works but I would have to edit more 100 team member pages.

How could I automatically load the URL from the "LinkedIn" link field into this script (it needs to be added into data-id="link comes here") and display on every team member page? Can this be done with Display Suite? Or do I need to write a module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [field template](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!theme!field.tpl.php/7) in your theme.

Call it something like `field--field-linkedin-url.tpl.php` (whatever you have called your field. I'm assuming `field_linkedin_url` for my example. Notice the _'s are converted to -'s in the file name.

In the template put the following html:

```
<script src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/MemberProfile" data-id="<?php print render($items); ?>" data-format="hover"></script>
```

It shows something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Scott. Yes, this is exactly how it should look like. I have implemented your approach, however, the link isn't loaded. If I look at the source, it looks like this:
    <a id="li_ui_li_gen_1381219277484_0-link" class="li-connect-link" href="javascript:void(0);">

Comment: Hm, this is strange. javascript:void(0) is what's supposed to be three. Still the LinkedIn profile isn't loaded on hover. The wheel is turning on hover, but the profiel doesn't open.

Comment: Got it. I am using Display Suite and there I had to reconfigure the Field display from "Title as link" to "URL, as plain text".
Now it works. Thanks Scott, can I buy you a beer or two?